# How to save a DataFrame to a csv file in spark 1.6?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a dataframe which contains two columns, uni_key and createdDate. I run an SQL query and save the results into `a`, and now i want to save these results onto a csv file. Is there any way to do this? Here's a code snippet:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
import csv



if len(sys.argv) != 2:

    print("Usage: cleaning_date.py <file>")
    exit(-1)
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
csvfile = sc.textFile("new_311.csv")
key_val = csvfile.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x)).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
result = key_val.filter(lambda x: getDataType(x[1]) == "valid")
myDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result, ('uni_key', 'createdDate'))
print(type(myDataFrame))
myDataFrame.registerTempTable("abc")
a = sqlContext.sql("SELECT uni_key FROM abc")
a.show()
# a.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("l.csv")
a.write.option("header", "true").csv("aaa.csv")
sc.stop()
```

this code gives the following error right now:

AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'csv'

Comment: does commented out line  `a.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("l.csv")`, not working?

Comment: no, commenting that out didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Builtin CSV writer has been introduced in Spark 2.0 and you clearly use Spark 1.x.

Either use [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path)
```

or update Spark to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @user7875578, I updated to spark 2 and it worked. :)

Comment: What should I do for PySpark `1.6.1` ?  when I am running `df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path)` I am seeing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv.`

Comment: @Candic3                launch pyspark using this command                                             pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0

Comment: @user2017 Yours is totally the real solution to tanvi question! He didn't specify being in Databricks, so user7875578 answer is wrong in general and very specific for an environment. Yours, on the other hand, is general and always reliable. 100% working, independently from the environment using Databricks or not.